# Pass parameters to xacro in launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody know how to pass parameters to a xacro file from a launch file? For example, if I want to run a xacro file five times in my launch file, each time with different parameter, is there any way of achieving that? Your help would be much appreciated.

Tom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/) by [TomWu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2605/tomwu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and solved it using the script but we found another way now. We use the following code to circumvent using tf_prefix because support has been dropped. I am not sure if this was added in hydro but we just tested the following code and it works. Please test with groovy and reply if it worked.

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find my_robot_description)/urdf/my_robot.urdf.xacro' prefix:=$(arg ns)" />
```

in the xacro file you can simply get the passed argument using $(arg prefix)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-02-06**:
Quick question: would you know the syntax to define a "default" value for the prefix argument in xacro? I can't run xacro.py to convert the xacro file to urdf because the argument is not set. Thanks for the tip anyway, it helped a lot!

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-02-06**:
Oh, I found a workaround, I can pass the argument on the command line, such as:
rosrun xacro xacro.py file.xacro > file.urdf prefix:=test

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2018-02-22**:
Just to help anybody else who may be having an issue here. You have to define your variable as a xacro:arg instead of a xacro:property. Someone at https://github.com/ros/xacro/issues/176 gave an example that really helped.

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-08-14**:
This ^ comment by @ChuiV is important for @kalectro 's answer to work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK xacro currently does not support this, but this would be an extremely useful enhancement.

A quick and dirty solution is to use a wrapper around xacro, and change your parameter value using sed. This is a somewhat primitive solution, though you should be able to get the correct functionality through a decently written shell script.

EDIT: Support for this feature was added in ROS Hydro. See @kalectro's answer.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-03-29**:
example link (404) removed as segbot code was migrated and released in Hydro, where this feature is available.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to use the argument to evaluate  [conditional blocks](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Conditional_Blocks)
e.g. load_camera:=0

```
<xacro:if value="$(arg load_camera)">
  <... some xml code here ...>
</xacro:if>
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5